# Rollback entire server but keep content

Tags: database, backups

Until recently I've only been doing mainly superficial support on a website.
But now the question has been asked to revert the server the website runs on, to a few months ago.
The website is Drupal, but runs in IIS with a Microsoft SQL database instead of MySQL.
Now, I've never done a backup/restore procedure from a website, nor do I know what the risks are or what needs to be done.
I was looking at https://www.drupal.org/node/22281, but I still don't feel wise/secure enough to know what I'll be doing.
The main problem for me is; I need to keep the content of the website as it is now, but I don't know for certain where this is located/stored. The database?
Changes in files haven't been done to the website as far as I'm aware, so I hope this won't amount to a problem.

Basically what I'm asking is; is there a way to be certain that a rollback of an entire server and then a restore of content wouldn't amount to any difficulties?

Any general (or specific) information would be much appreciated,
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can find the database information in your settings.php file.

A simple export of that database should allow you to capture the site as it exists currently, then when you get the server reconfigured you can simply import the exported database.